# calling a service from an activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, android-intent

I have been stuck on this issue for quite some time now.Have read the documentation and many tutorials and they just confuse me more.I hope someone will provide me a straightforward answer.It's really important.Thank you..
Ok ..so i want an activity to get some input from the user as and then send that string to a service.Then i want my service to run in a way so that i can use other applications while this one keeps running in the background.Also i don't want the service to keep running every second.What i want is for the service to get updated location of my current position every 10 minutes so i was thinkin if there could be a way to make my service to go to sleep n wake up evry 10 mins n check for updates.I don't want to show the update on the UI so i dont think i need to use an AIDL approach and also dont need to bind to the service.I js simply want to start the service as soon as the user enters the string and keep the service runing every 10 mins.I think it is really simple but m very confused.Please help.

Comment: This would help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188434/create-a-scheduled-service-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can start a service with a timer task of interval 10 min and do the desired task in the run method. 
 or by using handler with postdelaydmesage ..

[check this](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/34861.aspx)