# Create a Scheduled service in android

Tags: java, android, service, bluetooth, schedule

I need to create a schedule service in android with java. I have tried some codes , but all time after build the application it doesn't run. My logic is simple , I want to make a service to check the existence of a file in the bluetooth folder path, If this file is there , so this service will run another application , I need this with a schedule which run every 2 minutes.

Until now that's great, but now I have an error `The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type MyTimerTask`. I have tried this code...

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("/mnt/sdcard/Bluetooth/1.txt");

    public void run(){ 
        if (file.exists()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.MainActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } 
}
```

Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: Please post what you have tried?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve your requirement.

- TimerTask
- Alarm Manager Class

  TimerTask has a method that repeats the activity on the given particular time interval. look at the following sample example.

  ```
  Timer timer; 
  MyTimerTask timerTask; 

  timer = new Timer(); 
  timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
  timer.schedule ( timerTask, startingInterval, repeatingInterval );

  private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask 
  {
       public void run()
       { 
          ...
          // Repetitive Activity goes here
       } 
  }
  ```

  `AlarmManager` does same thing like `TimerTask` but as it occupies lesser memory to execute tasks.

  ```
  public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
  {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
      {
          try 
          {
              Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
              String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");
              Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } 
          catch (Exception e) 
          {
               Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
  }
  ```

AlarmClass,

```
private static Intent alarmIntent = null;
private static PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
private static AlarmManager alarmManager = null;

    // OnCreate()
    alarmIntent = new Intent ( null, AlarmReceiver.class );
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, alarmIntent, 0 );
alarmManager = ( AlarmManager ) getSystemService( ALARM_SERVICE );
    alarmManager.setRepeating( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ( uploadInterval * 1000 ),( uploadInterval * 1000 ), pendingIntent );
```

Comment: +1 I like your AlarmManager suggestion, leverages native Android classes/approach.

Comment: timerTask = new MyTimerTask(); sorry typo mistake. But i suggest you to go with Alarm Class.

Comment: How can you fix it so it will run even after user closed the app?

Comment: @Lucifer I think you missed mentioning Manifest Entry of the broadcast receiver. Specifically, mentioning the intents that will wake the receiver up.