# google-calendar API inform of event reminder

Tags: api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I need to integrate with google calendar, I have the basic stuff with API happening, but now realised that a reminder only informs [via email, SMS](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders)

So the google api "push notification", POSTs to a URL wont work with reminders...

So how can I inform in my app that a reminder is triggered, is there a work around?, checking email is not very scalable. And polling  the google calendar server, is not scalable either?, I will have to poll each user account on my solution?

How to notify of reminder with API?, thanks

[what are "pop ups" as other notifier method on above link for google-calendar?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question about [popup](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body), it is stated that reminders are sent via a UI popup.

```
EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
    new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
    new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
};
```

You may refer with this [SO thread: How to Create a Reminder Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208008/how-to-create-a-reminder-notification) wherein you need `AlarmManager` to schedule your notification at a regular bases (daily, weekly,..) and a `Service` to launch your notification when the AlarmManager goes off.